# Invoking UI Elements with Appium in Cucumber tests in Java Android results in build failed with alot of logs

Tags: java, android, cucumber, appium, cucumber-java

I have configured cucumber tests. Working fine for my activity.
I have also configured Appium UI Tests which are also working fine when invoked.
Now i want to invoke my activity's UI Elements with Appium under Cucumber tests which are written in stepdefinitions file.

My build.gradle

```
// Cucumber for E2E testing
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.5'

// Appium for DI  -- implementation / compileOnly
implementation 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
implementation files('libs/java-client-6.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar')
```

In Cucumber steps folder. I have written tests which are working fine. Checked through logs.
Now when i add code of appium in steps setup function to invoke LoginActivity and i can access UI elements like this:

```
@Before("@login-scenarios")
public void setUp() throws java.net.MalformedURLException {
System.out.println(Tag + "start - setUp in LoginStepdefs");

org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Emulator Nexus_4_API_22 Android 5.1.1, API 22");
capabilities.setCapability(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.my.app");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activities.MainActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
driver = new io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver(new java.net.URL("http://127.0.0.1:1234/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@After("@login-scenarios")
public void tearDown() {
System.out.println(Tag + "stop - tearDown in LoginStepdefs");
driver.quit();
}

@Given("^Login screen is launched$")
public void loginScreenIsLaunched() {
System.out.println(Tag + "1 - loginScreenIsLaunched");
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.id(com.my.app.utilities.Constant.APP_PACKAGE + signinEmailId)));
}
```

Now when i run my cucumber tests. Alot of logs in console and after some time build failed.

I am posting logs. Where i am wrong??

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void io.appium.java_client.ios.HasIOSClipboard.setClipboardImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/java-client-6.1.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `byte[] io.appium.java_client.InteractsWithFiles.pullFile(java.lang.String)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/java-client-6.1.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void io.appium.java_client.ios.HasIOSClipboard.setClipboardImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0/6bb22d04886b87f525e4ea352b1940a6ff8c471b/java-client-6.1.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `byte[] io.appium.java_client.InteractsWithFiles.pullFile(java.lang.String)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0/6bb22d04886b87f525e4ea352b1940a6ff8c471b/java-client-6.1.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void org.eclipse.jetty.util.preventers.AppContextLeakPreventer.prevent(java.lang.ClassLoader)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `org.apache.log.Hierarchy` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `org.apache.log.Logger org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger.getLogger()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    Expiring Daemon because JVM Tenured space is exhausted
    Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM memory
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper.\u003cclinit\u003e()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.cache.Striped64.getUnsafe()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.preventers.AppContextLeakPreventer.prevent(java.lang.ClassLoader)`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.hash.LittleEndianByteArray$UnsafeByteArray.getUnsafe()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

    Expiring Daemon because JVM Tenured space is exhausted
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.swing.JTree` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.tools.debugger.treetable.JTreeTable$TreeTableCellRenderer.updateUI()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `javax.swing.UIManager` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.tools.debugger.treetable.JTreeTable$TreeTableCellRenderer.updateUI()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
    JarCode: JSR encountered; reparse using JSRInlinerAdapter
    AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper.\u003cclinit\u003e()`","sources":[{"file":"/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}




> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5m 58s
21 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 15 up-to-date
Expiring Daemon because JVM Tenured space is exhausted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to build an [Appium](http://appium.io/)-based test with [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio) and compilation fails as Appium relies on [Java SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

So the architecture of your test should look like:

1. Application compiled with the Android SDK deployed on Android device (or emulator)
2. Your tests compiled with the Java SDK deployed on your computer
3. Android device (or emulator) connected to the computer via [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

This way your tests will control Android device and perform clicks, swipes, typing, assertions, etc. So you need to reconsider the approach of building your test project.

If you want UI tests to be an integral part of your Android application build consider switching to [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso), check out [How to Get Started with Espresso (Android)](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/getting_started_espresso/) to learn more about the concept/implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri for your time and response.
Yes i should consider switching to Espresso for this. I was also planning to do this.
Thanks again :)

Comment: I am marking your answer as right as Espresso get my work done. Thanks @Dimiti